# How to set Set Vm Arguements for Grails 2.2.4

Tags: grails, grails-2.2

I am using Grail 2.2.4,

in conf/spring/resources.xml, I try to import a file as ${realm}-config.properties, where realm is a vm arguement, I tried to set vm arguements in BuildConfig.groovy as below

**grails.tomcat.jvmArgs = ["-Dstage=dev","-Drealm=app"]**

But it doesn't seem to pick up. I get below error,

class path resource [${realm}-config.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist

What is the right way to set vm arguements in grails 2.2.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to load your config via environment variable handled in conf/Config.groovy

```
def ENV_NAME = "MY_CONFIG"
grails.config.locations = []
if (System.getenv(ENV_NAME)) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getenv(ENV_NAME)
}
else if (System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)) {
    grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.getProperty(ENV_NAME)
}
```